# How to combine two objects by means of a merger?

Tags: javascript

Good day. I came across such a problem and I can’t solve it for a long time. So, there are two multidimensional objects. I have to perform the operation of combining these two objects into one final object by merging them into a single object. The problem is that the object is multidimensional and I can’t correctly merge them by merging. By this [link](https://repl.it/repls/WaterloggedCyanKeygen) you can see the data of objects, below I will give a view of the final result.

```
[
  {
    text: 'A', children: [{
        text: 'B', children: [{
            text: 'C',
            children: [
              {text: 'B [43]', id: '43'}, 
              {text: 'B [93]', id: '93'},
              {text: 'B [11]', id: '11'},
            ]}
        ]}
    ]
  },
  {
    text: 'D', children: [{
        text: 'M', children: [{
            text: 'N', children: [
              {text: 'M [66]', id: '66'}
            ]}
        ]
    }]
  },
  {
    text: 'W', children: [
      {
        text: 'M', children: [{
            text: 'K', children: [
              {text: 'M [48]', id: '48'},
              {text: 'M [58]', id: '58'}
            ]
        }]
      }, {
        text: 'T', children: [{
            text: 'K', children: [{text: 'S [78]', id: '78'}]
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Anyway I add source objects:

```
const data_1 = [{
    text: 'A', children: [{
        text: 'B', children: [{
            text: 'C',
            children: [
              {text: 'B [43]', id: '43'}, 
              {text: 'B [11]', id: '11'},
            ]}
        ]}
    ]
  },
  {
    text: 'W', children: [
      {
        text: 'M', children: [{
            text: 'K', children: [{text: 'M [48]', id: '48'}]
        }]
      }, {
        text: 'T', children: [{
            text: 'K', children: [{text: 'S [78]', id: '78'}]
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
];

const data_2 = [{
    text: 'A', children: [{
        text: 'B', children: [{
            text: 'C',
            children: [
              {text: 'B [93]', id: '93'},
              {text: 'B [11]', id: '11'},
            ]}
        ]}
    ]
  },
  {
    text: 'D', children: [{
        text: 'M', children: [{
            text: 'N', children: [
              {text: 'M [66]', id: '66'}
            ]}
        ]
    }]
  },
  {
    text: 'W', children: [{
        text: 'M', children: [{
            text: 'K', children: [
              {text: 'M [58]', id: '58'}
            ]
        }]
    }]
  }
];
```

Here the union of all the elements takes place where they are present in one of the objects and absent in the other.

I understand that the task is not an easy one and it may not get a solution in this format, but I beg you not to pass by, at least give advice, share experience, offer an alternative, provide similar information, etc. etc.
It is very important for me to solve this problem, I will be very grateful for any help, meaning advice, useful information, and of course a solution.

Comment: please add all relevant data to the question, as well what youi have tried.

Comment: Where is the source object to be merged?

Comment: Ok, I added source objects.

Comment: what is the rule for merging? same `text` at same level?

Comment: Yes, You understood correctly.

Comment: Start writing some code. Write a function that merges the top level of the two objects. Once you have that up and running, you'll be better able to see how to do this recursively, all the way down the tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could reduce the arrays and check if the same `text` property exist, then check the children property, otherwise push the object to the actual result set.

This approach mutates the left array `a`.

```js
const
    merge = (a, b) => {
        b.forEach(o => {
            var item = a.find(q => o.text === q.text);
            if (item) {
                if (o.children) [item.children = item.children || [], o.children].reduce(merge);
            } else {
                a.push(o);
            }
        });
        return a;
    };

var data1 = [{ text: 'A', children: [{ text: 'B', children: [{ text: 'C', children: [{ text: 'B [43]', id: '43' }, { text: 'B [11]', id: '11' }] }] }] }, { text: 'W', children: [{ text: 'M', children: [{ text: 'K', children: [{ text: 'M [48]', id: '48' }] }] }, { text: 'T', children: [{ text: 'K', children: [{ text: 'S [78]', id: '78' }] }] }] }],
    data2 = [{ text: 'A', children: [{ text: 'B', children: [{ text: 'C', children: [{ text: 'B [93]', id: '93' }, { text: 'B [11]', id: '11' }] }] }] }, { text: 'D', children: [{ text: 'M', children: [{ text: 'N', children: [{ text: 'M [66]', id: '66' }] }] }] }, { text: 'W', children: [{ text: 'M', children: [{ text: 'K', children: [{ text: 'M [58]', id: '58' }] }] }] }];


[data1, data2].reduce(merge);
console.log(data1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your answers very cognitive.

Comment: I compared the two proposed solutions in more detail and noticed that your solution is more suitable for me. Thank you very much. By the way, could you pay attention to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58471985/how-remove-excess-property-from-object-by-condition) issue?

Answer (score 2):

For each level, you can group common objects (based on their `text` value) and recursively merge them if any of them have a `children` property:

```js
const data_1 = [{ "text": "A", "children": [{ "text": "B", "children": [{ "text": "C", "children": [{ "text": "B [43]", "id": "43" }, { "text": "B [11]", "id": "11" }] }] }] }, { "text": "W", "children": [{ "text": "M", "children": [{ "text": "K", "children": [{ "text": "M [48]", "id": "48" }] }] }, { "text": "T", "children": [{ "text": "K", "children": [{ "text": "S [78]", "id": "78" }] }] }] }];
const data_2 = [{ "text": "A", "children": [{ "text": "B", "children": [{ "text": "C", "children": [{ "text": "B [93]", "id": "93" }, { "text": "B [11]", "id": "11" }] }] }] }, { "text": "D", "children": [{ "text": "M", "children": [{ "text": "N", "children": [{ "text": "M [66]", "id": "66" }] }] }] }, { "text": "W", "children": [{ "text": "M", "children": [{ "text": "K", "children": [{ "text": "M [58]", "id": "58" }] }] }] }];

function mergeArrays(arr1 = [], arr2 = []) {
  const pairs = [...arr1, ...arr2].reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr.text] = acc[curr.text] || [];
    acc[curr.text].push(curr);
    return acc;
  }, {});

  return Object.values(pairs).map(([p1, p2 = {}]) => {
    const res = { ...p1, ...p2 };
    if (p1.children || p2.children) res.children = mergeArrays(p1.children, p2.children);
    return res;
  });
}

console.log(mergeArrays(data_1, data_2));
```

Note that this approach does not mutate the original arrays.

Comment: Thank you very much. I fan fp. It's good paradigm. Its good answer, thank you. 
I could ask you one question?  I have one common array, which contains all elements with "id" property. How I can compare array with it "id" properties with "id" properties result tree object? I need delete all elements from tree, which "id" matching with "id" in that array. Will be good, if it operation was happening in time create tree. 
I would be very grateful for answer on this question.

Comment: @Tomas happy to help :) But your second question is not very clear. Can you please post it as a separate post with sample input and output?

Comment: ok, thank you very much, right now I will note your answer as solution and I will publish new post.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58471985/how-remove-excess-property-from-object-by-condition) on new post