# How remove excess property from object by condition?

Tags: javascript

I have two object. I first object is an object which contains elements from second object. But in first objects contains such elements which are absent in the seconds object. I need remove all elements from first object that are not in second the object.

First object:

```
[
  {
    "text": "A",
    "children": [
      {
        "text": "B",
        "children": [
          {
            "text": "C",
            "children": [
              {
                "text": "B [43]",
                "id": "43"
              },
              {
                "text": "B [11]",
                "id": "11"
              },
              {
                "text": "B [93]",
                "id": "93"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "text": "W",
    "children": [
      {
        "text": "M",
        "children": [
          {
            "text": "K",
            "children": [
              {
                "text": "M [48]",
                "id": "48"
              },
              {
                "text": "M [58]",
                "id": "58"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "text": "T",
        "children": [
          {
            "text": "K",
            "children": [
              {
                "text": "S [78]",
                "id": "78"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "text": "D",
    "children": [
      {
        "text": "M",
        "children": [
          {
            "text": "N",
            "children": [
              {
                "text": "M [66]",
                "id": "66"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "text": "Q",
    "children": [
      {
        "text": "Y",
        "children": [
          {
            "text": "N",
            "children": [
              {
                "text": "I [15]",
                "id": "15"
              },
              {
                "text": "I [13]",
                "id": "13"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Second object:

```
[
  { id: "43", text: "B [43]" },
  { id: "93", text: "B [93]" },
  { id: "66", text: "B [66]" },
  { id: "13", text: "I [13]" }
]
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "text": "A",
    "children": [
      {
        "text": "B",
        "children": [
          {
            "text": "C",
            "children": [
              {
                "text": "B [43]",
                "id": "43"
              },
              {
                "text": "B [93]",
                "id": "93"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "text": "D",
    "children": [
      {
        "text": "M",
        "children": [
          {
            "text": "N",
            "children": [
              {
                "text": "M [66]",
                "id": "66"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "text": "Q",
    "children": [
      {
        "text": "Y",
        "children": [
          {
            "text": "N",
            "children": [
              {
                "text": "I [13]",
                "id": "13"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a function for filtering the nested array and hand over the array and a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) with the wanted `id`, which are kept in the result set.

In the function reduce the array by separating `children` from the object and filter the children.

If the `id` of the item is in the set or the children have some items push the object to the result set by checking the children as well.

```js
function filter(array, ids) {
    return array.reduce((r, { children = [], ...o }) => {
        children = filter(children, ids);
        if (ids.has(o.id) || children.length) r.push(Object.assign(o, children.length && { children }));
        return r;
    }, []);
}

var data = [{ text: "A", children: [{ text: "B", children: [{ text: "C", children: [{ text: "B [43]", id: "43" }, { text: "B [11]", id: "11" }, { text: "B [93]", id: "93" }] }] }] }, { text: "W", children: [{ text: "M", children: [{ text: "K", children: [{ text: "M [48]", id: "48" }, { text: "M [58]", id: "58" }] }] }, { text: "T", children: [{ text: "K", children: [{ text: "S [78]", id: "78" }] }] }] }, { text: "D", children: [{ text: "M", children: [{ text: "N", children: [{ text: "M [66]", id: "66" }] }] }] }, { text: "Q", children: [{ text: "Y", children: [{ text: "N", children: [{ text: "I [15]", id: "15" }, { text: "I [13]", id: "13" }] }] }] }],
    keep = [{ id: "43", text: "B [43]" }, { id: "93", text: "B [93]" }, { id: "66", text: "B [66]" }, { id: "13", text: "I [13]" }],
    result = filter(data, new Set(keep.map(({ id }) => id)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, good solution.

Comment: But how we can replace "var children" to const?

Comment: there is no need for const, because `children` is a parameter of the function. but why `const`?

Comment: okay I just don’t like var and come on. It’s hard for me to understand such code, could you give me a resource to learn this programming style?

Comment: what style do you mean?

Comment: By the way, how I can assign properties from "keep" array in result?

Comment: in this case, you could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) with a reference to the object and insert the value of the map as additional parameter of `Object.assign`.

Comment: I noticed that you are good at recursive programming, it’s hard for me to understand a recursive programming in fp and declarative style.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201172/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-tomas).